# Arranging three divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a layout of a webpage.

The header occupies the first 15% of the page vertically.
The body part occupies 70% in the middle.
The footer occupies the last 15%.

Here are my three divs basic layout:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

How do I do it in CSS?

The output should be something like the  in HTML4:

```
<frameset rows="15%, 75%, *">
    <frame />
    <frame />
    <frame />
</frameset>
```

## --- Updated: I forgot to check the parameters before + The Whole Stucture

Alright: I think I should copy and paste the whole structure here. The ones you guy provide me with are great but they didn't work out

```
<body>

<div id ="nav-header">
    <ul class="nobullet">
        <li><a href="">Exhibit</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Class</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Faculty</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Enterprises</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="main-container">
    &nbsp;
    <div id="extended"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <table id="info" bordercolor="black" rules="all">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">You're here: <div id="where"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><ul class="nobullet">
                <li><a href="">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Hire</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Collaboration</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Thanks</a></li>
            </ul></td>

            <td><ul class="nobullet">
                <li><a=href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a=href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a=href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">&copy;2013
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
```

Oh BTW: I am using Chrome.

## --- Update: Problem solved... Thanks to 3dgoo who commented here

Comment: What have you tried so far? Side Note - 20 + 75 + 15 = 110% :(. I am removing the javascript, jquery and html5 tags as this question seems to be just about CSS and doesn't involve any HTML5 elements.

Comment: @secyii your new HTML markup is missing closing tags, unbalanced tags, try making a fiddle in such type of cases

Comment: @Rex I forgot to pasted it so that won't be an issue

Comment: The [`center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is deprecated. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. `bordercolor` is not a valid attribute. `rules` is a deprecated attribute. `<div id="where"div>` is not valid html. You have mispelt your `</ul>` closing tag with `</ur>`. Your #info table has a comma in the tag, which is not allowed. Put effort into your question so people can focus on giving you a good answer, rather than trying to work around all your simple mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aWkzB/

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #header { height: 20%; background-color: blue; }
    #main { height: 75%; background-color: red; }
    #footer { height: 5%; background-color: green; }
</style>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I edited the post because it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    display:block;
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
#main {
    display:block;
    height:65%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#DCDCDC;
}
#footer {
    display:block;
    height:15%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/Z7tAU/)

Comment: I don't think `display:block;` is required because `div` tags are already block level. Also, the `width: 100%;`.

Comment: Required? No. But when you starting putting some content in there, you're going to want to keep them aligned.

Comment: I edited the post because it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is going bit out of 100 (20+75+15=110)

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
#header {
height: 15%;
background-color: yellow;
}
#main {
height: 70%;
background-color: green;
}
#footer {
height: 15%;
background-color: red;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/vBYJY/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.  It's a different approach but it does basically the same thing.

### *[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sMXeX/)*

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: #63D563;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 85%; /*15% header*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.main-content {
    background-color: #626262;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    bottom: 15%; /*70% content*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #63BCD5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    bottom: 0; /*15% footer*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```